# inserting/updating problem with foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

Problem is that when I run this loop it insert only a few rows from dataset. But there's many rows in dataset. Also in database has no rows. Why not my loop is working? I also want if data already have in database that will be updated with current dataset data.

```cs
  conn.Open();
  foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
     
 
 string cardno = row["cardno"].ToString();
 string style = row["style"].ToString();
 string process = row["process"].ToString();
 int quantity = int.Parse(row["quantity"].ToString());
 float price = float.Parse(row["price"].ToString());
 float total_price = float.Parse(row["total_price"].ToString());
 string month = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MMMM");
 int year = int.Parse(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy"));
 
 string queryInsert = "EXEC SP_AmountProcess '" + cardno + "','" + style + "','" + process + "','" + price + "','" + quantity + "','" + total_price + "','" + month + "','" + year + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "';";
 
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(queryInsert, conn);
 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
 dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
 //dataset.Reset();
 MessageBox.Show("Process Success");
 conn.Close();
```

```sql
 :::Store Procedure (SP_AmountProcess)::::
 CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_AmountProcess]
  @cardno nvarchar(50),
  @style nvarchar(255),
  @process nvarchar(255),
  @rate float,
  @quantity int,
  @amount float,
  @month nvarchar(50),
  @year int,
  @process_time datetime
 
 AS
 
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT '#' FROM TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT WHERE YEAR =@year AND MONTH=@month AND CARDNO= @cardno)  
 BEGIN  
 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT]  SET [CARDNO] =@cardno,[STYLE]=@style,[PROCESS]=@process,[QUANTITY]=@quantity,[RATE]=@rate,[AMOUNT]=@amount,[MONTH]=@month,[YEAR]=@year,[PROCESS_TIME]=@process_time  WHERE YEAR =@year AND MONTH=@month AND CARDNO=@cardno ;  
 END  
 ELSE  
 BEGIN                                              
 INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT] ([CARDNO] ,[STYLE] ,[PROCESS] ,[QUANTITY] ,[RATE] ,[AMOUNT] ,[MONTH] ,[YEAR] ,[PROCESS_TIME]) VALUES (@cardno,@style,@process,@quantity,@rate,@amount,@month,@year,@process_time); 
 END ;
```

Comment: No idea why you only get a few rows, but you have a major SQL injection problem. Do *not* concatenate the values in, pass them as proper parameters. Also you need a `using` for the connection and command objects. Consider using `SqlBulkCopy` or a Table Valued Parameter to do this whole thing in bulk, and no loops, it will be much much faster.

Comment: Under most situations, a DataTable holds typed data - which means those gyrations of converting to string and parsing into a typed variable is pointless.  Also, the basic DB provider objects will insert and update as needed with a simple `Update()` method.  It elides the stored procedure, but likely seems a worthwhile tradeoff. A few hours reading the docs for those tools might be well worth it.

Comment: sidenote: don't use the prefix `sp_` for you procedures. Read all about that [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: you check with not exists if you can find any rows, and if you cannot find any rows then you do an update and if you find rows than you do an insert. Are you sure that is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

change this approach in sp please check i think this might be helpful to u..

:::Store Procedure (SP_AmountProcess)::::

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SP_AmountProcess]
  @cardno nvarchar(50),
  @style nvarchar(255),
  @process nvarchar(255),
  @rate float,
  @quantity int,
  @amount float,
  @month nvarchar(50),
  @year int,
  @process_time datetime
 
 AS
 
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT '#' FROM TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT WHERE YEAR =@year AND MONTH=@month AND CARDNO= @cardno)  
 BEGIN  
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT] ([CARDNO] ,[STYLE] ,[PROCESS] ,[QUANTITY] ,[RATE] ,[AMOUNT] ,[MONTH] ,[YEAR] ,[PROCESS_TIME]) VALUES (@cardno,@style,@process,@quantity,@rate,@amount,@month,@year,@process_time); 
 END  
 ELSE  
 BEGIN   
 UPDATE [dbo].[TBL_PROCESS_AMOUNT]  SET [CARDNO] =@cardno,[STYLE]=@style,[PROCESS]=@process,[QUANTITY]=@quantity,[RATE]=@rate,[AMOUNT]=@amount,[MONTH]=@month,[YEAR]=@year,[PROCESS_TIME]=@process_time  WHERE YEAR =@year AND MONTH=@month AND CARDNO=@cardno ;                                             
 
 END ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).